# Join two rows of the same table which points to the same thing in another table

Tags: mysql, join

TableA

```
key    |    col1         | col2        |
=========================|=============|
1      |    1            |1            |  
2      |    2            |3            |
3      |    10           |5            |
4      |    55           |7            |
```

TableB

```
B_key    |    col3         |
=========================|
1      |    NAME1        |
2      |    NAME2        |
3      |    NAME3        |
7      |    NAME7        | 
10     |    NAME10       |
55     |    NAME55       |
```

Expected Result

```
|    col1_join    | col2_join
==================|=============
|    NAME1        |NAME1
|    NAME2        |NAME3
|    NAME10       |NAME5
|    NAME55       |NAME7
```

I have two tables A and B. Col 1 and Col 2 are foreign keys that refer to table B's PK.

What I want is a way to join these two tables A and B and get the corresponding COL3.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM 
    tbl_A 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_B 
ON 
    tbl_A.col1 = tbl_B.B_key 
OR
    tbl_A.col2 = tbl_B.B_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do as

```
select 
b1.col3 as col1_join,
b2.col3 as col2_join
from TableA a 
left join TableB b1 on b1.B_key = a.col1
left join TableB b2 on b2.B_key = a.col2
```